# Can't make allowBlank true visually in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have textfield:

```
{
                xtype : 'textfield',
                id: 'specialCode',
                allowBlank: true,
                fieldLabel : 'Special Code',
                name : 'specialCode'
            }
```

I do make it required when a checkbox is checked with

```
Ext.getCmp('specialCode').allowBlank = false;
Ext.getCmp('specialCode').validateValue(Ext.getCmp('specialCode').getValue());
```

I becomes red and it becomes required.

Then when another checkbox is cheked I use this code

```
Ext.getCmp('specialCode').allowBlank = true;
```

It becomes not required but the red border does not go away. I need to click the field and some other place in order to remove the red border.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `clearInvalid` on the field too to reset it's invalidation style.

```
Ext.getCmp('specialCode').allowBlank = true;
Ext.getCmp('specialCode').clearInvalid();
```